# compare array elements with json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, iteration

I have an array that consists of json objects like:

```
defaultProperties: Array[2]
 0:Object
   name: "test1"
   desc: "description of test1"

 1:Object
   name: "test2"
   desc: "description of test2"
```

I have another JSON object which is collection of many objects and looks like this:

```
dataset['Information'] -> Object
   test1: Object
   test2: Object
   test3:Object
```

I need to check if test1 and test2 from defaultProperties exist in dataset['Information']. If no i have to store test1 and test2 else skip it.

I tried with following way. But does not seem correct. Do you have any ideas how to do this?

```
var informationJson = dataset['Information'];
    for (var index = 0; index < informationJson .length; ++index) {
     for(var i =0;i<defaultProperties.length;i++)
         {
            if(informationJson [index] == defaultProperties[i].name){
               break;
             }
            else
              {//store it}
         }

    }
```

Comment: Is dataset['Information'] an array or a hash? From textual view it looks like a hash (object) but the way you're looping over it looks like it's an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `dataset['Information']` is a hash (object), something like this might work:

```
var informationJson = dataset['Information'];
for (var i=0; i<defaultProperties.length; i++) {
    if (informationJson.hasOwnProperty(defaultProperties[i].name)) {
        continue;
    } else {
        //store it
    }
}
```